# I got composer install error under php 7.4

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I try to run laravel 7.26.1 app under php 7.4.10 (I worked under php 7.3 before) in Kununtu 18 and I got error on composer install command:

```
In ComposerRepository.php line 637:
                                                                                                                                                                   
  Could not load package mews/purifier in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint ~4.*: Invalid version string "~4.*"  
                                                                                                                                                                   

In VersionParser.php line 485:
                                                                          
  Could not parse version constraint ~4.*: Invalid version string "~4.*"
```

In composer.json, which I did not modify from 7.3:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "cartalyst/sentinel": "^4.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^7.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "illuminate/database": "^7.27",
        "illuminate/events": "^7.27",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "livewire/livewire": "^1.3",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.2",
        "prettus/l5-repository": "^2.6",
        "realrashid/sweet-alert": "^3.1",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.6",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.19",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^5.1",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
    }
}
```

Is syntax of this file wrong?
What have I to change in it?
have php 7.4 some other rules?

Thanks!

Comment: Strange. Maybe something is wrong with your composer.lock file? First thing I would try is to update the package with composer update. Updating composer is an option, too. In the end I would for a fresh composer.lock.

Comment: I removed composer.lock and run again composer update with same results

Comment: What version of composer do you have? You can run composer self-update to update.

Comment: $ composer self-update
                                        
  Command "self-update" is not defined.  
                                         

$ composer --version
Composer 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17

Comment: This is a horribly outdated version of Composer. Please try updating it. If the error persists, please provide further details. After all, that version constaint looks pretty strange to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your composer version seems to be old. Try to install composer like described on
[getcomposer.org/download/](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Comment: I tried to to run commands at the top of the link, but still have Composer 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17. Have I to remove current Composer firstly? If yes how?

Comment: Ah I see. I forgot to mention that this installs composer into the current directory. So you should have a compoer.phar in the directory where did the setup process, right?
You can now use "sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer" to have composer globally available via "composer" command.

Comment: Have i TO RUN sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  after thE COMMANDS IN THE LINK ?

Comment: Thanks! I have composer --version 
Composer version 1.10.13 2020-09-09 11:46:34.

Comment: Nice. That is the latest stable version right now. Now you should also be able to use composer self-update